# Linked list Square from another list

Tags: java

I want a program to return the list of squares of another list passed in as a parameter.

My problem is how to pass a list as a parameter. I do not understand this.

Comment: `magic(yourListObject)` in this way, `yourListObject` is a parameter to the `magic` method.

Comment: Where's your code? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
    List<Integer> numList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,  10);
    List<Integer> squaresList = numList.stream().map(x -> x*x).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(numList);
    System.out.println(squaresList);
```

If you specifically need a `LinkedList` implementation, you can use this:

```
    List<Integer> numList = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,  10));
    List<Integer> squaresList = numList.stream().map(x -> x*x).collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
    System.out.println(numList.getClass());
    System.out.println(squaresList.getClass());
```

Comment: Thanks man . This is nice of you

Comment: @zeyad, if you get an answer, you should mark one of the answers as accepted.